# internal microphone detected and working in Ubuntu; not detected in Devuan

Tags: debian, ubuntu, audio, devuan

I'm on Dell Latitude 3420; it came with pre-installed Ubuntu 20.04.

I am dual booting with Devuan Daedalus

**uname -a**

```
Linux devuan-Latitude 6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-2 (2023-07-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The internal microphone works fine with Ubuntu, but not with Devuan.
Earlier there was no sound output also. But that was resolved after installing `firmware-sof-signed`

**Other firmware installed are**

```
firmware-linux-free
firmware-amd-graphics
firmware-intel-sound
firmware-linux-nonfree
firmware-misc-nonfree
```

**Other info:**

```
description: CPU
          product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1264MHz
```

I discovered a hint from `lspci -nnk` in both my Devuan and Ubuntu partitions.

Saved the output of this command and did a `diff -y`. I found that the "kernel drivers in use" are the same for all the PCI and devices except for the Multimedia audio controller. Devuan [left] and Ubuntu [right].

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation | 00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation
    Subsystem: Dell Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology      |Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0b20]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel                      |Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

Can this info be of any use for us?
Thanks in advance.

Regards.